# How to set the file name when using the 'imwrite' function

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I want to save the image with the name I want. 
I am using the following code now, but I want to change the name whenever I save it.

However, the 'imwrite' function can only be saved to a given name within the code.

Is there a way to set a name to save when the Save button is pressed?

```
raw = cv2.imread('picture', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
cv2.imshow('raw',raw)
if key == 27 :
            break
elif key == ord("c"):  #save button
            print("snap")
            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path) + str(now) + ".png", raw) 
 #path is already setting on front
```

Comment: you can use random string to save it or create a counter, that add a one each time you press button.

Comment: yes, i know that but it isn't what I want. i hope when i press button, system ask me like "what do you want your file name?"  then i type the name and save image. but i don't have any idea to do this :(

Comment: but thanks your comment !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edited code :

```
raw = cv2.imread('picture', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
cv2.imshow('raw',raw)
if key == 27 :
            break
elif key == ord("c"):  #save button
            val = input("Enter your value: ")
            print("snap")
            cv2.imwrite(val + ".png", raw) 
 #path is already setting on front
```